# Very long time execute queries with NOT NULL expression in Derby DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, derby

I have table with name ATTACHMENT with follow columns:

```
COLUMN_NAME          TYPE_NAME  COLUMN_SIZE
---------------------------------------------------
DTYPE                VARCHAR    31
ID                   VARCHAR    36
VERSION              BIGINT     19
TYPE                 INTEGER    10
FILENAME             VARCHAR    100
DATA                 BLOB       9437211
SIZE                 INTEGER    10
CHECKSUM             BIGINT     19
AUTHOR               VARCHAR    36
FILEDATE             DATE       10
FILETIME             TIME       8
CREATIONDATE         DATE       10
CREATIONTIME         TIME       8
FILETYPE             INTEGER    10
SYSTEM               SMALLINT    5
ORIGINALPICTUREID    VARCHAR    36
COMPRESSEDPICTUREID  VARCHAR    36
FIRSTUSE             VARCHAR    120
```

And when I have run simple test SQL query:

```
SELECT ID FROM ATTACHMENT WHERE ORIGINALPICTUREID IS NOT NULL;
```

This query execute very long time (30 sec.)

But when I have run next test SQL query without IS NOT NULL expression:

```
SELECT ID FROM ATTACHMENT WHERE ORIGINALPICTUREID IS NULL;
```

This query execute only 2 sec.

In real system I have script:

```
select ATTACHMENT.ID,
       ATTACHMENT.SIZE,
       ATTACHMENT.AUTHOR,
       ATTACHMENT.FILENAME,
       ATTACHMENT.FILETIME,
       ATTACHMENT.FILEDATE,
       ATTACHMENT.CREATIONDATE,
       ATTACHMENT.CREATIONTIME,
       ATTACHMENT.FILETYPE,
       ATTACHMENT.COMPRESSEDPICTUREID,
       ATTACHMENT.ORIGINALPICTUREID,
       ATTACHMENT.FIRSTUSE
from ATTACHMENT,
     MESSAGECONTENT_ATTACHMENT,
     MESSAGECONTENT
where ATTACHMENT.ID not in (select distinct ATTACHMENT.ORIGINALPICTUREID
                            from ATTACHMENT
                            where ATTACHMENT.ORIGINALPICTUREID is not null)
and   ATTACHMENT.ID not in (select distinct COMPRESSEDPICTUREID
                            from ATTACHMENT
                            where ORIGINALPICTUREID is not null)
and   MESSAGECONTENT_ATTACHMENT.MESSAGECONTENT_ID = MESSAGECONTENT.ID
and   MESSAGECONTENT_ATTACHMENT.ATTACHMENTS_ID = ATTACHMENT.ID
and   ATTACHMENT.DTYPE = 'P'
and   MESSAGECONTENT.PERSONIDPATIENT = '0584393a-0955-4c9b-98f7-d31c991d22a3'
and   (ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%jpeg' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%jpg' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%tiff' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%tif' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%bmp' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%gif' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%png' 
       or ATTACHMENT.FILENAME like '%ser')
```

and this script execute very, very long time.

Could you please help me how I can solve problem with IS NOT NULL expression in my SQL query in my Derby DB?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered a filtered index?

Comment: Yes, I have trying use index, but it did not help.

Comment: Using WHAT index? Can you include that information in the question please? Also how many rows are we talking about, and why do you think `LIKE '%png' OR LIKE '%gif'` will ever be fast? This will require a scan. You should consider storing the type (or a type category) separately, so you can seek instead of parsing every filename in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are killing yourself on this query primarily due to your distinct of not nulls... You are blowing through ALL ATTACHMENTS TWICE for original and compressed respectively, yet you are only interested in a single patient.  I've restructured the query to START with the WHO you want... The patientPersonID.  From that, join to the message attachments.  You only care about anything that is attached to this ONE PERSON.  This should result in a very small set of records.  Of THOSE records, only THOSE do you care to look at the attachment table itself and see if any qualify for your DPTYPE, like condition and IS NULL.

I would ensure you have an index on your messagecontent table on (PersonIDPatient) at a minimum, and if any other columns AFTER the first position, no problem.  The joins to the other tables appear to be on their respective primary ID column and would assume that you have indexes on those.

```
SELECT 
      atch.ID, 
      atch.SIZE, 
      atch.AUTHOR, 
      atch.FILENAME, 
      atch.FILETIME, 
      atch.FILEDATE, 
      atch.CREATIONDATE, 
      atch.CREATIONTIME, 
      atch.FILETYPE, 
      atch.COMPRESSEDPICTUREID, 
      atch.ORIGINALPICTUREID, 
      atch.FIRSTUSE 
   FROM 
      MESSAGECONTENT msgCont
         JOIN MESSAGECONTENT_ATTACHMENT msgAtt
            ON msgCont.ID = msgAtt.MESSAGECONTENT_ID
            JOIN ATTACHMENT atch
               ON msgAtt.ATTACHMENTS_ID = atch.ID 
              AND atch.DTYPE = 'P' 
              AND atch.ORIGINALPICTUREID IS NOT NULL
              AND atch.CompressedPictureID IS NOT NULL
              AND (   atch.FILENAME LIKE '%jpeg' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%jpg' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%tiff' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%tif' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%bmp' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%gif' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%png' 
                   OR atch.FILENAME LIKE '%ser')
   WHERE 
      msgCont.PersonIDPatient = '0584393a-0955-4c9b-98f7-d31c991d22a3'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have used your solution and now request working during 2 sec. vs. 7 min. previously!

Comment: @IwanKochan... yeah, just a little bit faster :)  The LIKE comparisons are probably a bigger hit on the time for you.

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN operator in queries does not make use of any indexes. -

Avoid using NOT IN operator in your queries.

In order to to find results which does NOT meet a certain criteria it has to check ALL the records against the condition, which makes presences of indexes irrelevant.

Also instead of using wildcard % try making use of Full-Text indexes and query the database something like

Select Col1, Col2 , .......

from Table

Where Col1 CONTAINS(Col1,'Search') AND Col1 CONTAINS(Col1,'Search2').........